# how to do binding in Spring annotated request parameter?

Tags: spring, annotations

i have a controller that is using annotation for request mapping and requestParam.

the controller is working fine. However when submitting a command object with array, spring will crap out saying **array index out of bound**. i am guessing there is something wrong with binding but don't know how to fix it.

to be more specific, in eclipse i would set debugger at the beginning of the controller, and when submitting the form (by hitting a input submit button) eclipse debugger will not trigger and i will see **array index out of bound** error in console.

the controller is something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/internal/pcsearch.dex", "/external/pcsearch.dex"},
        method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView executeProductCatalogSearch(
        HttpServletRequest request,             
        @RequestParam(value = "cat" ,required = false) String cat,          
        @RequestParam(value = "brand" ,required = false) String brand,
        @ModelAttribute("command") ProductCatalogCommand cmd
        ){
```

[edit]
and the jsp is like:

```
<form name="pForm" 
id="pForm" 
action="<c:url value="psearch.dex"><c:param name="cat" value="${cat}"/></c:url>" 
method="POST" 
style="display:inline;">
...
...
<c:forEach var="model" items="${models}" varStatus="modelLinkStatus">
        <script>
            var modelImg<c:out value="${modelLinkStatus.index}"/>Src = '<c:out value="${model.altModelImage}"/>';
        </script>
        <spring:bind path="command.models[${modelLinkStatus.index}].modelSkusDisplayed">
        <input type="hidden" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>"/>
        </spring:bind>  
<spring:bind path="command.updateCartButton">
                                        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="orderEntryMessages.ecatalog.button.addToCart" text="Add to Cart" htmlEscape="yes" />" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" class="sub_buttons"/>
                                    </spring:bind>
```

...

and the command object declare the model array as:

```
private List<ModelLink> models = new ArrayList<ModelLink>();
```

where modelLink is a custom ds.

the first foreach tag handle the the model command object and the 2nd part is the submit button i clicked on.

Comment: can you post ProductCatalogCommand class, and may be your jsp form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use AutoPopulatingList as models to bind list to view and controller. for example please refer [link](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=12). This might resolve your problem of index.